# Google sign-in for flutter web - Change account

Tags: flutter, google-signin, flutter-web

I am using google_sign_in_web 0.10.2 https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web and following the posted [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart)

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
            _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
          setState(() {
            _currentUser = account;
          });
          if (_currentUser != null) {
            _handleGetContact(_currentUser!);
          }
        });
        _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
      }
```

I would like to have the user be able to change their google account in case they had several. For example, when you are in google maps, drive, or any other google application, you can add and switch to another account. Is there a way for a user to do this with this library?

Thank you.

Comment: Well that would mean a single user will have multiple google accounts associated with their account. Then you can no longer consider google account as unique identity of a single account

Comment: I didn't understand your question !
you want user to login first from his google account and after the login he can choose that he want to use gmail,gdrive with same user login details ??

Comment: You cant do like that. You must sign out from app and login again with another gmail.

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ you can have several Gmail accounts and when, for example, you go to google maps, or drive, there is a dropdown at the top with a circle to switch account or log in with a new one. You don't have to logout from one and log in with the other, you can switch accounts

Comment: @SankethB.K a single user can, in fact, have multiple google accounts. If you look at the example in the library, you will see it returns a list of the contacts. It may happen that a user made a mistake and wanted the list of their contacts from a different account. I hope this clarifies the reason for making this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that without custom code, since at this point your app doesn't know about all the different google accounts a user has access to.

To reach the goal you want you can provide a button for switching the account. If there is a valid login you need to logout the user. If not this is not needed. Everytime some login succeeds on the device, you can save the acount email at the device. This is how you can implement it.

Now here is the complete example using `SharedPreferences` and `Google Sign in`

```
class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DemoPage> createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {
  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    logoutUser() async {
      await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    }

    getSignInOptions() async {
      SharedPreferences pre = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      List<String> possibleAccounts = pre.getStringList("loggedInAccounts") ?? [];
      // Now you have the accounts, you can do navigation or force UI to show the accounts
      // After that a user clicked on of the accounts in the ui you can
    }

    // Method to sign-in an user using Google
    void _signInUsingGoogle() async {
      bool isSignedIn = await this._googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
      SharedPreferences pre = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();


      this.firebaseUser = this.firebaseUser ?? _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

      // after 1st time signin
      if (isSignedIn && this.firebaseUser != null) {
        print("user name signed in");
        print("display name" + this.firebaseUser.displayName);
        print("email: ${this.firebaseUser.email}");
        pre.setStringList("loggedInAccounts", ["testaccount@gmail.com"]); // <--- you need to put the email in here
        // This is just an example, it would be better to get the current list before and compare the values before saving everything
      } else {
        // first-time sign in
        GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
        GoogleSignInAuthentication signInAuthentication =
            await signInAccount.authentication;

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: signInAuthentication.idToken,
          accessToken: signInAuthentication.accessToken,
        );
        UserCredential userCredential =
            await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        print("user name" + userCredential.user.uid);
        this.firebaseUser = userCredential.user;
        print("firebaseUser name" + firebaseUser.displayName);
      }
    } // end of signIn

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                // Make sure you autlogout user
                if (isSignedIn) {
                  await logoutUser();
                }
                await getSignInOptions();
        
              },
              child: Text('Sign in with different account'))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now before calling `getSignInOptions();` we need some information about the current login state. thats where we log out a user if there is a valid login or we keep it as it is and call `getOtherAccounts();`. In this function you can read every account email which was logged in at this device. Its recommended not to save any sensible data, so I would only save the email address, to provide it in the ui, but you have to get the password from the user with an input. Now you can provide the possible accounts and you simply have to do some UI work to create the view with the choosen email and an input for the password. Now if you call `_signInUsingGoogle()` and its sucessfull, you can save the new login. This is just an example, it would be better to get the current list and compare the values before saving everything. I commented the line where you should add that.